# How to ensure a SQL like NOLOCK when using Django Model Queries

Tags: sql, django, pyodbc

I have a Django Model "Users" tied to an existing MS SQL Server database table. I am reading the table thus:

```
Users.objects.filter(userid='xyz').filter(status='active')
```

I want to know what locking constructs would this translate to, as in, would this sort of a read Lock the table? In SQL I would have done:

```
SELECT * from users (nolock) where userid='xyz' and status='active'
```

Is there a way to explicitly specify a "nolock" via Django Model queries?

Searched a lot in the Django as well as django-pyodbc documentation without any success.

Thanks.

p.s.: Using django-pyodbc and pyodbc drivers

Comment: Curious as to why the NOLOCK hint is needed in this scenario? Or is this just a nice-to-know kind of question?

Comment: I simplified the query to ask the question, it is more complex. Nice to know as well :)

Comment: Fair enough :)...FWIW I think you'll have to resort to raw SQL

Comment: Yes, I came up with the same conclusion. Was able to see some of the queries that Django was generating and they seem quite primitive. Using raw SQL now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view:

```
create view dbo.vw_Users
as
select  col1
,       col2
,       ...
from    dbo.Users with (nolock)
```

And have Django read from the view instead of the table.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that or also use raw SQL but wanted to know if there's a way to use the Django Model Programming constructs and force a NOLOCK. Thanks anyway.